# Definition of the power of the determinant of a matrix

Tags: matrices, definition, determinant

Suppose, I have a square matrix $A$. Now, what is the definition of $[det(A)]^{n}$? Have mathematicians attempted to define it, or is it such a no-brainer/straightforward that they never attempted to define it?

Comment: The determinant is just a number. Don't overthink it.

Comment: The definition of $a^n$ is $\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdots a}_{n\text{ times}}$

Comment: It would help to know where you saw this notation, if you did.  In some treatments it is convenient to an author to refer to $\det A$ as $|A|$, although this creates a certain amount of confusion with the use of $|\cdot |$ for an absolute value.

Comment: @hardmath so can I write $|A|^{2}$ without creating any problems while doing a math?

Comment: $\text{det}(A)^n = \text{det}(A^n)$, so it's simply the determinant if the $n$-th power of the matrix.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic $\lvert A \rvert^2$ has a perfectly fine definition: compute $\lvert A \rvert$ (which is just a number), then square it.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic: I'd suggest sticking to $\det(A)$ because the notation $|A|$ makes it seem like that number would always be non-negative which it certainly isn't.

Comment: I would understand $|A|^2$ as the square of the determinant if your context was that $A$ was a square matrix of size greater than $1\times 1$.  However it is always best in writing up a passage for others to read to explain any unconventional or ambiguous notation.  Here $\det A$ is unambiguously the determinant of (square) matrix $A$, and the alternative $|A|$ is commonly used when the entries of $A$ replace mention of $A$, e.g. in [Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) for solving linear systems.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to ask about its *significance/meaning* rather than its definition (which is indeed straightforward).